# Weird result for Array.indexOf

Tags: scala

The following code produces a value for `-1` for index. Why is that?

```
val values = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, Double.NaN, 4.0)

val index = values.indexOf(Double.NaN)
println(s"index = $index")
```

What is the best way to find the index of NaN in this scenario? I have the following solution but don't think that's the most elegant one.

```
val index2 = values.zipWithIndex.find(_._1.isNaN).get._2
println(s"index2 = $index2")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Double.NaN != Double.NaN`.

You can use [`indexWhere(p: (T) ⇒ Boolean): Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array) as follows:

```
val index = values.indexWhere(_.isNaN)
```

Answer (score 8):

`indexWhere` is like `indexOf` but allows you to provide your own predicate (which is necessary here since `Double.NaN != Double.NaN`):

```
scala> values.indexWhere(_.isNaN)
res0: Int = 3
```

This will be a little more efficient than your solution, and doesn't throw an exception if none of the elements are `NaN`.